# How do I refresh fragments in tabbed activity according to changes in main activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to refresh my `incomefrag` and `expenditurefrag` when a date is selected. Here is what I did. It does not change according to change in date but changes when another tab is selected.

The activity that calls the fragments. Since the code is more than 200 lines pasting only imp parts.
In this activity I select the from and to dates. I want the `incomefrag` and `expenditurefrag` to change according to the change in date and not when I slide between the tabs.

```
// extends AppComactActivity
private void setupViewPager(final ViewPager viewPager) {
    SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new IncomeCatFrag(), "Income");
    adapter.addFragment(new ExpenditureCatFrag(), "Expenditure");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
            viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    });

}
```

The `SectionsPageAdapter`

```
public class SectionsPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }
    public SectionsPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

This is my `incomefrag`. expenditure frag is similar.

```
//extends Fragment
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.income_frag, container, false);
    populate1(); // implemented later. searches through db to fill textviews etc.
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all 
Use LocalBroadcastManager  in your main activity to broascast an intent (when ever changes occurs).

2nd step:
register a broadcast receiver in you tabbed activity to receive broadcast intent from main activity

3rd step:
once you receive a broadcast in tabbed activity set you tab number on viewPager relevant to that fragment:
e,g viewPager.setCurrentItem(YOUR TAB NUMBER)

```
MainActivity{ //send your broadcast when date changes
           `Intent intent = new Intent("my_date_change_intent_name");
            intent.putExtra("key", "dateChanged");
           LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent); }`


TabbedActivity{//register your broadcast receiver and receive broadcasts 
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(MyReceiver,new IntentFilter("my_date_change_intent_name"))`;
BroadcastReceiver MyReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
if (intent != null ) {
 String str= intent.getStringExtra("key");
 //Now set your tab number on viewPager
viewPager.setCurrentItem(YOUR_TAB_NUMBER)
}
}
}
});
```